# C++ Looping user input until correct

Tags: c++, loops, input

I am asking the user for input in the range of 0 - 127, if they don't put the correct value I want the program to keep asking them until they input a correct value.

At the moment I have the following code in a class:

```
void setNoteNumber (int value)
{

    number = value;

    while (value < 0 || value > 127) {

    std::cout << "This number is not in the range of 0 - 127, please select a new value: ";

    }
}
```

It kind of works, apart from if they input the wrong value my console repeatedly displays the error message. If anyone can help me it would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks!

Comment: Where is the input coming from?

Comment: What type is `number` of? And what is it used for?

Comment: I think the best way is that you use a debugger and go step by step through the code. Then you learn and see what's wrong. This is much better than only read the solutions here because this is a very basic question and it's important that you understand what's going on.

Comment: This is a section from a class, the int number value is initialized at the beginning of the class and is private. The value is replaced by user input in the main() function

Answer (score 2):

The program design is currently wrong, `value` doesn't change in the while loop, so it is infinite. Something like this might work better:

```
bool setNoteNumber(int value); //return false if value is outside range
//main loop
do {
    value = getInput();
} while(setNoteNumber(value))
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use cin (ask user for input) inside of the loop for it to actually work. Since you're not showing the cin call, I'm assuming it's outside of the function, but it needs to be inside of the while loop, since you want to ask user repeatedly.

Answer (score 1):

Your design is wrong. an `if` statement would work a lot better.

Example:

```
if (value < 0 ||value > 127) {

std::cout << "This number is not in the range of 0 - 127, please select a new value: ";

}
```

Your loop is wrong because it is infinite, because when value < 0 && Value > 127, it will always run. Your not modifying the value of `value` at all. A loop doesn't really make sense.

Comment: @user3484634 It also depends on what your doing. I didn't realize that at the start, but I think maybe what you wanted to do was to let it iterate until you get a correct value, where a loop with a continue; statement might work better.